# How do I get the PrimeVue Galleria component to display the new image when the image is edited?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, galleria, primevue

I have a PrimeVue Galleria

```
<Galleria 
  :value="images"
  v-bind:activeIndex="activeIndex"
  :showThumbnails="false"
  >
  <template #item="slotProps">
    <Image :src="slotProps.item.objectURL" />
  </template>
</Galleria>
```

I pass the current image which I obtain by using the activeIndex into an image editor. The image editor returns a new objectURL. This new objectURL is emitted to the component containing the Galleria, where the old image's objectURL is replaced with the newly edited image's objectURL/

Right now, the image gets updated properly. However, the Galleria does update the image unless you switch to a different activeIndex and back.

So far, I've tried re-rendering the component itself once the image is received, however, this doesn't seem like a very ideal solution.

How do I get the Galleria to reflect the edited image immediately after it was received?